# How can I display only prime numbers in this code?

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to get all prime numbers in the range of 2 and the entered value using this c++ code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int result = 0;

    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {    
        for (int b = 2; b <= num; b++) {
            result = i % b;

            if (result == 0) {
                result = b;
                break;
            }              
        }

        cout << result<< endl <<; 
    }
}
```

the problem is that I think am getting close to the logic, but those threes and twos keep showing up between the prime numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should show the wrong output.

Comment: Step 1: check if the number is prime, and remember whether the number is prime. Step 2: If the number is prime, print it. You seem to be having trouble with the *remember whether the number is prime* bit, is that right?

Comment: just few hints: 
you are always displaying the number, regardless of whether it is prime or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your code and added comments where I did the changes

The key here is to understand that you need to check all the numbers smaller then "i" if one of them dividing "i", if so mark the number as not prime and break (the break is only optimization)

Then print only those who passed the "test" (originally you printed everything)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int num = 0;
    int result = 0;

    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
       bool isPrime = true; // Assume the number is prime

       for (int b = 2; b < i; b++) { // Run only till "i-1" not "num"
            result = i % b;

            if (result == 0) {
                isPrime = false; // if found some dividor, number nut prime
                break;
               }

       }

      if (isPrime) // print only primes
          cout << i << endl;  
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, there are many possible optimization, but when explaining to someone what's wrong with his solution I'm trying to make as few changes as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers have been given which explains how to do it. None have answered the question:

> What am I doing wrong?

So I'll give that a try.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int result = 0;

    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {    
        for (int b = 2; b <= num; b++) {  // wrong: use b < i instead of b <= num
            result = i % b;

            if (result == 0) {
                result = b;  // wrong: why assign result the value of b?
                             // just remove this line
                break;
            }              
        }

        cout << result<< endl <<; // wrong: you need a if-condtion before you print
                                  // if (result != 0) cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kenney - sorry, was I just a few seconds a head?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your code.

Simplest algorithm (not the most optimal though) is for checking whether N is prim is just to check whether it doesn't have any dividers in range [2; N-1].

Here is working version:

```
int main() {
    int num = 0;

    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        bool bIsPrime = true;
        for (int b = 2; bIsPrime && b < i; b++) {
            if (i % b == 0) {
                bIsPrime = false;
            }
        }

        if (bIsPrime) {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Just to add, you can improve the code a bit by halving the inner loop, changing `for (int b = 2; bIsPrime && b < i; b++)` to `for (int b = 2; bIsPrime && b < (i/2 + 1); b++)` ... You don't need to test for divisors beyond half of the number

Comment: @WhiZTiM You actually don't need to check past the square root of the number.  Most implementations check `b * b < i`

Answer (score 0):

I can pretty much guess its academic task :)

So here the think for prime numbers there are many methods to "get primes bf number" some are better some worse.

[Erosthenes Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) - is one of them, its pretty simple concept, but quite a bit more efficient in case of big numbers (like few milions), since OopsUser version is correct you can try and see for yourself what version is better

```
void main() {
  int upperBound;
  cin >> upperBound;

  int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int)sqrt((double)upperBound);
  bool *isComposite = new bool[upperBound + 1]; // create table
  memset(isComposite, 0, sizeof(bool) * (upperBound + 1)); // set all to 0

  for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {
        if (!isComposite[m]) { // if not prime
              cout << m << " ";
              for (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m) // set all multiplies
                    isComposite[k] = true;
        }
  }

  for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++) // print results
        if (!isComposite[m])
              cout << m << " ";

  delete [] isComposite; // clean table
}
```

Small note, tho i took simple implementation code for Sive from [here](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (writing this note so its not illegal, truth be told wanted to show its easy to find)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pulling out the logic of determining whether a number is a prime to a separate function, call the function from `main` and then create output accordingly.

```
// Declare the function
bool is_prime(int num);
```

Then, simplify the `for` loop to:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) { 
   if ( is_prime(i) )
   {
      cout << i << " is a prime.\n"; 
   }   
}
```

And then implement `is_prime`:

```
bool is_prime(int num)
{
   // If the number is even, return true if the number is 2 else false.
   if ( num % 2 == 0 )
   {
      return (num == 2);
   }

   int stopAt = (int)sqrt(num);

   // Start the number to divide by with 3 and increment it by 2.
   for (int b = 3; b <= stopAt; b += 2)
   {
      // If the given number is divisible by b, it is not a prime
      if ( num % b == 0 )
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   // The given number is not divisible by any of the numbers up to 
   // sqrt(num). It is a prime
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I think thats overdoing it :)

Comment: @Inverce, in what sense?

Comment: In short http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaa83.jpg what user needs vs what user gets ^^, however i do agree to make functions not too long, but in some cases there is no, reason to make em if they are part of whole :)

Comment: @NathanOliver oww thats true, i remember how it felt when one day my colleague has proven me that. Terrible feeling...

Comment: @Inverce, I get to differ on that principle. I tend to think in terms of abstractions. Implementing `is_prime` inline is not the best strategy, IMO.